# MVC4 and Entity Framework 5 stored procedures

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi Im trying to access a database table in my mvc4 application using a stored procedure and Entity Framework 5. 
I created a FormValueModel.edmx file and imported the User Table and the GetUser Stored Procedure

Here is the code for the GetUser Stored Procedure

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    [User].[User]
Where
    @UserName = UserName 
    AND @UserPassword = UserPassword
    AND Active = 1
```

Here is the code in my Controller to access the stored procedure

```
using (var db = new FormValueEntities())
{
    string userName ="TestUser"
    string password = "Password"

    var query = db.GetUser(userName, password);

}
```

Why cant I access the table by using query.UserName or query.UserPassword ect.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to take the first item from the query i.e.

```
var user = db.GetUser(userName, password).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: @JohandeKlerk actually it *does* work then, it's your query that's returning 0 results.

Comment: Ok thanks but why do you think it returns null? I tested the stored procedure and it returns the table with all the data.

Answer (score 0):

you need to do something like this:

```
var query  = (from a in db.GetUser(userName, password)
select new User
{
   UserName =a.UserName 
    ...other fields
}).tolist();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the Stored Procedure!!!

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    [User].[User]
Where
    @UserName = UserName 
    AND @UserPassword = UserPassword
    AND Active = 1
```

Good:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    [User].[User]
Where
    UserName = @UserName 
    AND UserPassword = @UserPassword
    AND Active = 1
```

Comment: This doesn't help me. It doesn't matter in what order the Variables are assigned